# How to repair chrome websocket options?

Tags: google-chrome, websocket

I am using Chrome 16. Since yeasterday i had no problems with opening websockets but something happened and now when i try to open websocket at websockets.org I receive this message - "Unexpected response code: 200" - at the console.I tried to uninstall it several times and change versions (Chrome 14) with no result. How can e repair my browser?
PS: I read that status 200 means OK for opening a websocket but the socket is disconnected.

Comment: `200` is not correct for WebSockets; it should be `101`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome 14+ supports the newer HyBi protocol series (same with Firefox 6+). I don't believe that websockets.org has been updated yet to support that yet.

**Update:**

websockets.org has now been updated to support the HyBi/IETF 6455 version of the protocol.

Comment: Last time I read Firefox stopped the support of websockets over security issues. And I am almost 100% sure that last week I use Chrome 14 and there was no problem with websockets.org.

Comment: Addressing the perceived security issue was one of the big changes in the HyBi protocol series. Also, Firefox never officially supported WebSockets until version 6.0. In version 4 and 5 they had the older Hixie implementation that was disabled by default (but could be enabled via about:config). In a few months the latest stable versions of Chrome, Firefox, Opera and IE will likely all support WebSockets (HyBi).

Comment: Thank you your answers are great and accurate!

Comment: FIREFOX 7, not 6. Firefox 6 supports one version older.

Comment: Firefox 7+ and Chrome 14+ support version 8 (based on hybi-10). Firefox 6 supports version 7.

Comment: @Roger, there is very little wire change between HyBi-07 and HyBi-10 (or any recent HyBi version for that matter). Once you have a WebSocket server working against one HyBi version, adding support for all of them (except HyBi-00 which is just Hixie-76) is trivial (I've done it). The changes are mostly just handshake header names and close codes. So really, it is correct to say that Firefox 4/5, Chrome 5-13 support Hixie and Firefox 6+, Chrome 14+ supports HyBi.

Comment: Based on that analysis, it's also correct to say that they all support everything. WebSockets are an upgrade to HTTP and the browers have been able to handle HTTP for quite some time. It's just the little things. :)

Comment: @Roger, I don't know what you mean by "they all support everything." Each browsers version only supports one protocol version. Different servers might support Hixie or not but most that support HyBi support the variations (or could trivially support them). While WebSockets uses the HTTP upgrade mechanism, WebSockets is not an "upgrade to HTTP". It's really a message based TCP transport that has an HTTP friendly handshake, but after the handshake is no longer HTTP at all.